# MySQL - How to count the number of inserts/updates to a table

Tags: mysql

I'm looking into some MySQL performance issues and would like to generate a report of how many inserts/updates are made to each table in my database over some period of time.

I have lots of data available regarding server performance in general such RDS's disk I/O metrics.  MySQL's `SHOW STATUS` command show `Queries` and even `Innodb_data_writes`, but these are all at the entire server level, not granular at all.  I'd like to get detail down to the table level.

Perhaps there is something buried in the `information_schema` or `performance_schema` databases that I can turn on or use?

Comment: You can add an update timestamp to each table, if you don't have them, then just search on the dates.

Comment: Never had to do this, but this may be usefull:
http://ronaldbradford.com/blog/mysql-dml-stats-per-table-2009-09-09/

Comment: @johnelemans the problem with that is if things are updated multiple times between counting the items updated since the last timestamp.  It gives you an idea, but still not as accurate as I'd like.

Comment: I see. AFAIK there is no built in solution. I have seen the use of a TRIGGER on UPDATE used to increment a counter. A bit more costly, but you can set up triggers on Insert and Update to count both types of events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The performance schema keeps statistics of table io, on a table (and even index) granularity.

See table `performance_schema.table_io_waits_summary_by_table`

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/table-waits-summary-tables.html#table-io-waits-summary-by-table-table

Comment: Perfect, that does exactly what I was hoping.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to barat for pointing out [this link](http://ronaldbradford.com/blog/mysql-dml-stats-per-table-2009-09-09/) which suggests going through the binary log for the relevant information. I coded up a quick script that uses a combination of `mysqlbinlog` to retrieve the binary log from a remote server and regex parsing of the log contents into something that outputs the desired information in the format:

```
Parsed 1,096,063 lines spanning 300 seconds between 2016-09-13 03:05:00 and 2016-09-13 03:10:00
master                         metrics                        update          = 43570
master                         metrics                        insert into     = 9
DEFAULT                        accounts                       update          = 501
DEFAULT                        users                          update          = 5
DEFAULT                        logins                         insert into     = 1
mysql                          rds_heartbeat2                 insert into     = 1
```

Code shared on Github at https://github.com/sellerlabs/mysql-writes-per-table